# php parse syntax error on cartthrob checkout

Tags: cartthrob, php, error, parse, syntax

On my **cartthrob** site I can add and remove things to and from the cart just fine but when i go to checkout i get this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ':' or '{' in
>   MYSITE/system/expressionengine/third_party/cartthrob/payment_gateways/Cartthrob_ct_pay_by_check.php
>   on line 52

ive found the file and the line its referencing is

```
public function charge($credit_card_number){
        switch ($this->plugin_settings('processing_status'))
```

is there something wrong with this that I should edit?
or is the cause of the problem somewhere else?

**EDIT :**
Redownloaded cartthrobs files, opened the one in question and found out what was missing, guess my initial download mustve got corrupted or something